# R: Regression between Two related Dependent Variables (not paired)

Tags: r, regression, time-series, categorical-data, functional-data-analysis

I have two dependent variables that are measured during an experiment, they both change in time (independent variable).  The measurements for both variables do *not* always coincide in time (so they are not really paired).  I know that there is a relationship between the two measured dependent variables, and ultimately, **I want to use this relationship to predict the value of one dependent variables based on the other dependent variable**. In essence, I want to:

> Perform a regression between Two related but not paired Dependent Variables

**The following example is an illustration that sets up the data so that it can be explained (hopefully) using R and pertinent packages:**

I am cooking dough in an oven at very low temperature.  I have instrumentation to measure *humidity* (a probe), and *crunchiness* (my jaws). Because of the nature of the experiment, I wasn't able always measure both variables at the same time.  The extended literature in the subject tells me that both variables change logarithmic growth/decay as the dough cooks.

Because I only have only one jaw (measuring crunchiness), but have unlimited use of the humidity probe (measuring humidity), I want to use the relationship between both variables to predict crunchiness based on humidity (R script is highly appreciated).

Here's a plot of the data:
[image]

Here's the data (so it can be used to solve my predicament), and the code to plot it.

```
df <- read.table(text=
"CookMinutes    Value   Measurement
21  6.5 Humidity
17  7.0 Humidity
32  7.0 Humidity
29  6.9 Humidity
111 6.5 Humidity
135 6.4 Humidity
159 6.1 Humidity
15  7.3 Crunchiness
12  6.7 Crunchiness
14  7.4 Crunchiness
26  8.4 Crunchiness
12  7.0 Crunchiness
24  7.8 Crunchiness
135 10.9    Crunchiness
159 11.2    Crunchiness",
                       header=T)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=CookMinutes, y=Value, color=Measurement, shape=Measurement)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, formula = y ~ log(x))
```

> **I still have this question** (about 4 years after) .  The answers are very compelling AND innovative, but I cannot believe there isn't a method out there to solve this predicament.  More recently I have tried looking into methods in time series, as that is a case where you may have independent measurements over time that are not aligned to each other and you may want to understand the relationship between both and the confidence between that relationship.

Comment: Couple of questions: 1) Where is the humidity sensor located? In the air or inside the dough? 2) What are the independent factors that are contributing to these changes other than change in temperature? 3) Are you expecting something like `log(crunchiness) = a log(humidity) + b` where we have transformed both variables and find `a` and 'b' using OLS?

Comment: Hi @bikhaab, Please take the example with a grain of salt as *Any resemblance to reality is pure coincidence*  **1)** the sensor is located in the middle of the dough (the example is just an illustration). **2)** in this example, everything is kept the same, the only independent variable changing is time, the oven is perfect, and somehow the system is not perturbed when I do my measurements.  **3)** That relationship looks enticing, but I don't want to impose.  Note that the measurements do not always coincide in time.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your actual data, you might be able to approach this as an imputation problem. The higher the fraction of value pairs is in your data, the better it would work.

```
df1 <- merge(df[df$Measurement ==  "Humidity", ],
             df[df$Measurement ==  "Crunchiness", ], by = "CookMinutes", all = TRUE)

library(Amelia)
set.seed(42)
df1i <- amelia(df1[, c("CookMinutes", "Value.x", "Value.y")], ts = "CookMinutes", polytime = 1, m = 50)
plot(df1i) #not so good

library(data.table)
df2i <- rbindlist(df1i$imputations[sapply(df1i$imputations, is.list)], idcol = "Imp")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2i, aes(x = CookMinutes, y = Value.x)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Imp)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", color = "red")
```

[image: plot1]

```
ggplot(df2i, aes(x = CookMinutes, y = Value.y)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = Imp)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = median, geom = "point", color = "red")
```

[image: plot2]

```
df2i[, id := seq_len(.N), by = Imp]
ggplot(df2i[, .(x = median(Value.x), y = median(Value.y), 
                imputed = (sd(Value.x) != 0) + (sd(Value.y) != 0),
                t = unique(CookMinutes)), by = id], 
       aes(x = x, y = y, color = ordered(imputed), size = t)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: plot3]

The relationship between the two variables appears to change over time. Note that you'd need a model that takes into account errors in both x and y values if you want to model this (Deming regression, ...).

Obviously, imputation could be improved and you could (maybe should) even use the proposed "logarithmic growth/decay" model for imputation. But you said in a comment "That relationship looks enticing, but I don't want to impose."

Comment: Hi @Roland, if it is not too much trouble, how would you use the logarithmic model to improve the imputation?

Comment: I'd probably simply fit the models, bootstrap the predictions and use the bootstrap resamples to propagate the uncertainty to the x-y-model.

Comment: THANK you very much @Roland.  I used your script, used the MI and Norm packages as well and will try the prediction method when I figure it out.  However, upon playing with the parameters, I just came to the conclusion (maybe wrong) that the imputation techniques I used add an arbitrary amount of uncertainty.  When using these methods, confidence intervals grow or shrink depending on the parameters that are used (number of sets, smoothing parameters, etc.).  So it feels like we are adding uncertainty arbitrarily and not reading the uncertainty of the model and trying to keep it constant.

Comment: You could also look at it as comparing two *functions*,  so m,aybe look into functional data analysis.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is learn the relationship between time and the crunchiness and between time and the humidity, and then relate these two to each other. It is sort of similar to the "imputation solution" but instead of using imputed data points you use the function.

The log model seems about right so I am using that one. Both the crunchiness and the humidity are functions of the log of time:

$$
\begin{align}
\text{crunchiness} &= \beta_\text{crunchiness} \log(\text{time}) + \alpha_\text{crunchiness}\\
\text{humidity} &=  \beta_\text{humidity} \log(\text{time}) + \alpha_\text{humidity}\\
\end{align}
$$

An expression for the log of time in terms of humidity can be obtained by rewriting the log-linear model for humidity.

$$
log(\text{time}) = \frac{\text{humidity} - \alpha_\text{humidity}}{\beta_\text{humidity}} \\
$$

This term is inserted in the log-linear model for crunchiness. With this we can express the crunchiness as a linear function of humidity.

$$
\begin{align}
\text{crunchiness} &= \beta_\text{crunchiness} (\frac{\text{humidity} - \alpha_\text{humidity}}{\beta_\text{humidity}}) + \alpha_\text{crunchiness} \\
&= \frac{\beta_\text{crunchiness}}{\beta_{humidity}} \text{humidity} - \frac{\beta_\text{crunchiness}\alpha_{humidity}}{\beta_\text{humidity}} + \alpha_\text{crunchiness} \\
&= \beta \times \text{humidity} + \alpha
\end{align}
$$

These new $\alpha$ and $\beta$ translate from $\text{humidity}$ to $\text{crunchiness}$. Below is the code for doing this in R. A plot shows that the log-linear fit of the predicted points is equivalent to the log-linear fit of the original crunchinenss points. However, the predicted points are much more spreaded out.

```
library(tidyverse)
# learning log-linear model for humidity and crunchiness
df_humidity     <- df %>% filter(Measurement == "Humidity")
df_crunchiness  <- df %>% filter(Measurement == "Crunchiness")
fit_humidity    <- lm(Value ~ log(CookMinutes), df_humidity)
fit_crunchiness <- lm(Value ~ log(CookMinutes), df_crunchiness)

# computing new linear function from humidity to crunchiness
slope     <- coef(fit_crunchiness)[2] / coef(fit_humidity)[2]
intercept <- -slope * coef(fit_humidity)[1] + coef(fit_crunchiness)[1]

# Showing the predicted data
df <- df_humidity %>%
  mutate(Value = slope * Value + intercept,
         Measurement = "Predicted_crunchiness") %>%
  bind_rows(df_humidity, df_crunchiness)
ggplot(df, aes(CookMinutes, Value, color=Measurement, shape=Measurement)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ log(x))
```

[image: The log-linear relation of the predicted points is equal to the log-linear relation of the original points]

Comment: Hi @Pieter, thank you very much for this approach.  With your approach, the uncertainty from the _Humidity_ translates into the _predicted-crunchiness_, thus the confidence intervals of the _predicted-crunchiness_ become larger.  I used this approach to do the opposite, _i.e._ to predict the Humidity based on the Crunchiness, and in that case, the _predicted-humidity_ had a much tighter confidence interval than the original _Humidity_, which makes sense for the approach, but in my mind, I should be injecting more uncertainty and not reducing it.

Comment: I guess that is because the `Humidity` is more or less constant, i.e. the intercept is more important than the slope. Finding a relation from `Humidity` to `Crunchiness` therefore leads to large variations in the predictions while the other way around leads to stable/constant predictions. Hence, the predictions for the latter (`Humidity`) are not so much influenced by the `Crunchiness` measurements. That's why I noted this.

Comment: Also, note that the formula's only express the MLE prediction. There is nothing in there about the confidence. I guess you can do something similar with the confidence intervals.